# Why is my form triggering the wrong controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post, asp.net-mvc-routing

This form has multiple submit buttons, when clicked, it calls a simple JavaScript function to change the value of a hidden input (function is called "setHidden".  This worked before, after some other not relevant code, it has ceased working.
Essentially, the action it is supposed to call is never called, instead it seems to default back to a previous URL.

The Form:

```
<form action="/League/RemoveOwner" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="1007" name="lid"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="index" name="index"/>
    <input type="image" src="../../Resources/Images/Delete.png"
           height="12" alt="Remove Owner" title="Remove Owner"
           onclick="setHidden('index', '1031')"/></a> coach<br />
</form>
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveOwner(int id, string index)
{
    //yada
    return PartialView();
}
```

When clicking the image, it should call the remove owner controller, instead it calls the "View" controller:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)  {  
//yada
return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your routes and solution folders structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

After searching high and low, I finally found the problem.  There was another form on the page that didn't have a closing tag.  THAT form was supposed to take it back to the "View" controller. It was on a partial, so I didn't catch it until... well until I had racked my brain for 2 hours...

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for you form action code is don't write the absolute path for your form action. You could use the Html.BeginForm() or write your site url in the web.config and fetch it to the Application["URL"] while the application start at global.ascx. Then your form should look like:

```
<form action="<%=Application["URL"]%>League/RemoveOwner">
```

This approach can avoid some errors while publishing to the IIS or another web server.